# Rails routing for a return url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have set a delivery url for delivey reports of an sms app from kannel this way;

```
id = rand(36**8).to_s(36)
https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/messages/delivery?id=#{id}&type=%d
```

and in messages controller is

```
def delivery
sent_message =  SentMessage.find_by_ref(params[:id])
if params[:type] == 1
  sent_message.delivery = "Delivered"
  sent_message.save()
elsif params[:type] == 2
  sent_message.delivery = "Delivery Failure"
  sent_message.save()
else 
  sent_message.save() 
end
```

From my routes file is the following is the line

```
 match 'message/:id/delivery' => 'messages#delivery', :as => :deliver
```

Someone help me point out the error because the delivery reports are simply not being reported.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you paste the error you're seeing?

Comment: @Orlando there is no error is its something that happens in the background.

Comment: What about the log output for that call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For route like `https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/messages/delivery?id=#{id}&type=%d` you should use:

`match 'messages/delivery' => 'messages#delivery', :as => :deliver`